# What my traceroute only list one hop?

Tags: networking, traceroute, gateway

This is my topology in my network.

[image]

It's easy to know my server can communicate to `172.18.32.254/24`.

But when I `traceroute` the path, I only get one hop to it.

[image]

My doubt is why it do not through 102.10.10.254?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your diagram, it looks like the "gateway switch" is one device (a router) with multiple IP addresses: 172.18.32.254 and 102.10.10.254.

Your server 102.10.10.1 originates the first traceroute packet with a TTL of 1.  The packet arrives at the "gateway switch" on the 102.10.10.254/ibr.100 interface.  The packet is accepted.  The router notices that one of its own ip addresses (172.18.32.254) is the destination and delivers the traceroute packet to the upper-layer stack for processing.  This results in a response from 172.18.32.254.

Going between 102.10.10.254 and 172.18.32.254 does not count as a "hop" because that is the same device.

The original traceroute packet never has its ttl decremented.  Per [When is an IPv4 TTL decremented and what is the drop condition?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10929/when-is-an-ipv4-ttl-decremented-and-what-is-the-drop-condition) a router only decrements a ttl once it has decided to forward it.

More simply, your server IS ONE NETWORK HOP from 172.18.32.254.  Multiple interfaces/ips on a router is not a hop.

Answer (score 0):

There is no hop for traceroute to see in between 172.18.32.254 and 102.10.10.254 since these are bound on the same device.